# django url is giving page not found (404) error

Tags: django, django-urls

I am getting page not found(404) error for votings app that I created from datacamp tutorial. I have checked my code to make sure it's free of errors. admin is working fine but other urls are not.

Here's urls.py code from the main application directory:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
        path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
        path('votings/',include('votings.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here's urls.py from the votings app directory:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.index, name='index'),
        path('<int:question_id>/',views.detail, name='detail'),
        path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
        path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

I am using django 2.0.5.

Thanks

Comment: Why are both urls.py modules similar? Where is the urls.py of votings app?

Comment: one is in mysite directory and the other one is in mysite/votings/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've made a mistake copying the wrong `urls.py` for votings app, the problem has to be it.

This is the main urls.py of your project:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
        path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
        path('votings/',include('votings.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

FYI, according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) `include()` adds urls from your app directory's (in your case it's voting) urls.py to the main urls.py (in memory). This keeps the main urls.py from getting too big to read.

And this is the urls.py of your **votings app** which is literally the copy of **main urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
        path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
        path('votings/',include('votings.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Don't you see any problem here? There's no endpoint. Where's the associated view (function-based or class based) for this url?

I suggest writing a view in your views.py and test it out:

Votings app views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Votings app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.current_datetime, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Edited my original post to reflect the correct code.

Comment: @Yasin Can you please post the entire traceback along with views.py or any link to source code?